# Laravel: module is not stored to the database

Tags: laravel, methods, routes

When I try to upload something to the database using the create method, this is not stored in the database. It looks like the page just refreshes. I am quite new to Laravel so any help would be appreciated.

Below I provided respectively the top of my blade view, my route and my controller. Is someone able to help me? I've searched in many other topics but couldn't find the solution to my problem.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <form action="/module" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

        @csrf
        

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8 offset-2">
                <div class="row"><h3>Add New Module</h3></div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="title" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Module Title</label>


                    <input id="title"
                           type="text"
                           class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror"
                           name="title"
                           value="{{ old('title') }}"
                           autocomplete="title" autofocus>

                    @error('title')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror

                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="category" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Category</label>


                     <select id="category" onchange="getCategories()" class=" mt-1 block w-full py-2 px-3 border-gray-300 bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm p-1.5 px-3 border-2  @error('category') border-red-500 @enderror">
                        <option disabled selected value> -- Kies één van de opties -- </option>
                        <option value="Schil">Schil</option>
                        <option value="Afbouw">Afbouw</option>
                        <option value="Installatie">Installatie</option>
                        <option value="Afwerking">Afwerking</option>
                    </select>

                    @error('category')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror

                </div>
```

Route:

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
    });
    
    Auth::routes();
    
    Route::get('/module/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\ModulesController@create');
    Route::post('/module', 'App\Http\Controllers\ModulesController@store');
```

Controller:

```
class ModulesController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('modules/create');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'title' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
            'description' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'price' => ['required', 'string'],
            'category' => ['required', 'string'],
            'subcategory' => ['required', 'string'],
            'image' => ['required', 'image'],
        ]);



        auth()->user()->modules()->create($data);


        
    }
}
```

Comment: In the action field have you tried to type "{{route('module')}}"? Also there is no need for the @method('POST'), since you already told the form how the request should be sent in the method field.

Comment: Where does it show that error: in PhpStorm or on the actual website (so it's a Laravel runtime error)?

Comment: @LazyOne it shows the error in the browser

Comment: What URL do you get the error on?  And what did you do to get to that URL and error?

Comment: When I try to go to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/module" it shows this error: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

Comment: You have shown us you have a GET route for `/module/create`, and a POST route for `/module`, but no GET route for `/module`.  So yes, of course if you GET `/module` you will see an this error ... Why are you visiting that URL? Did you mean to visit `/module/create`?  What is the problem?

Comment: Well, I am trying to upload a module, however the module is not uploaded to the database. I have to say I am quite new to working with laravel but isn't the /module supposed to load a "not found" page? And in the "/module/create" page you can create a module and the it has to redirect to "/module" page

Comment: Nothing loads any page/response unless you a) set up a route for it, and b) set up a controller method to handle that route. You have a GET route for `/module/create`, and the `create()` method to handle it.  You also have a POST route for `/module`, and the `store()` method to handle that, so when you submit your form that's the code handling it.  But that `store()` method doesn't return a response or send you anywhere after the `create()` runs, so you won't see any response in the browser.  And none of this has anything to do with what happens if you GET `/module`.

Comment: From your comments, I think the real problem is that your `store()` method is not doing what you want, and this has nothing to do with what happens when you visit /module.  If so, edit your question (and title) to clarify ...

Comment: @Bots I added an answer, does it help?

Comment: Yes it did, thank you! and sorry for not replying. I am still struggling to pass all of the data to the database...

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem 1

You mention "*It looks like the page just refreshes*" - this sounds like what might happen when there is a validation problem, right?  Checking your code, I don't see anywhere that would display the validation errors.  So maybe validation is failing, Laravel is bouncing you back to the form to tell you there is a validation error - but those errors are not displayed, so it looks like you just refreshed the page!  This matches exactly what you describe.

How to display validation errors is [described clearly in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors).  Include this code somewhere on your form page:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

#### Problem 2

Because of the first problem, you haven't hit this one yet, but once it is fixed you will.  Once your new model has been `create()`-d, nothing at all happens in the current code.  This means you'll see a white/blank page in the browser after you submit the form, which is not a great user experience.  So what do you want to do?  Often redirecting to some kind of index list of the thing you just created is the way to go.  For eg, maybe you'd like a page listing all the current user's modules.  Convention would be to have that at `/modules`, so at the end of your `store()` method you could have something like:

```
return redirect('/modules');
```

Note this is just an example and won't actually work until you:

- add a route for that URL;
- add the corresponding controller method which generates the list;
- add a view to display that list;

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need `@method('post')` just remove it.
and better to named the post route to `Route::post('/module', [App\Http\Controllers\ModulesController::class, 'store')->name('module.store');`
then `action={{ route('module.store') }}`
and should you have `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>`
before `</form>` closing tag

Comment: Thank you! However, this gives me a new error: Route [modules.store] not defined

Comment: Try to run `php artisan route:cache` from terminal

Comment: You should never cache routes in development.  [From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-caching): "*... you should only run the route:cache command during your project's deployment.*". Maybe you meant `php artisan route:clear`.

Comment: `php artisan route:cache` will be registered by a single method call within a cached file, if there are hundreds of routes it will be improved performance on routes registration time. Since it uses PHP serialization you may find that sometimes only controller based routes are being cached, and also PHP not able to serialize other routes.

Comment: "During deployment" you can call `php artisan route:cache` (not production). If you add any new routes (usually we do during development) you will need to generate a fresh route cache.